# k-line / kwp2000 adm mercedes benz ECU

Tags: c

I am going to find out local parameters from ADM MERCEDES BENZ ECU.
I have already connection to it and sending and receiving to/from it by kline of speed 10400.
My problem is that I found out for example engine speed could be detected by sending
0x87 0xa8 0xf2 0x22 0x1d 0x05 CS
which a8 is the ecu address and f2 is my address and 22 is read data bu common identifier .
but I can not understand 1d and also 05 .
could anyone please help me about it and its responses.
I also need to fin out vehicle speed and some other parameters .
thank you

Comment: You may lookup the manual of the device. It seems hard to find on the internet.

Comment: Actually I could not find its manual .
it 's for  o457 Mercedes Benz .

Comment: Then ask Mercedes for help might be the better solution. It's hard to find in publicity might be NDA related.